# I want to get pick out a value scanned from a method and get sum of 3 instances of the method

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is the code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class recycleBeta {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Insert bottles with pant A");
    System.out.println(bottleList(1));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Insert bottles with pant B");
    System.out.println(bottleList(2));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Insert bottles with pant C");
    System.out.println(bottleList(3));

}

    public static String bottleList(int args) {

        Scanner bottler = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = 0;

        ArrayList<String> bottles = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Press 1 and enter for each bottle, end with 0");

        String cont;

        while (!(cont = bottler.next()).equals("0"))
        {       
            bottles.add(cont);
            count++;
        }
        return ("You have inserted " + count + " bottles");


    }
}
```

I want to add a certain multiplier to each of the bottleList(1),(2) and (3).

So say that "count" value in bottleList(1) would be multiplied by 1.5, bottleList(2) by 2.0 and bottleList(3) by 3.0.

I would also like to sum the total amount of bottles scanned from the 3 instances in the Main method. At this stage though, I'm clueless on how to do so without creating 3 different method to call upon, which seems a bit redundant. If you have any suggestions as to improve the code a bit, I'm all ears (I'm 4 weeks into programming Java).

Comment: your problem is not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually use the "args" parameter you pass to the bottleList method.

Change the type of "args" from int to double, pass in 1.5, 2, 3 then add something like this at the end of the method.

```
return ("You have inserted " + (count * args) + " bottles");
```

Unless I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.  Also change the name of args to something with meaning, like "multiplier".

Comment: As I said I'm new to programming, so thanks for explaining your suggestion in newcomer-friendly way. This was what I was looking for, so thank you.